# Pandas: Speed up filtering by creating index?

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to use pandas like SQL for a web app (instead of holding the data in pSQL, just hold it in a pandas DataFrame since the data is just under 1GB and is not changing constantly). If I am doing a look up based on multiple filters on columns (eg. age > x, age < y, income > p, income < q) are there any ways to speed up this filtering? or is it already done below. In SQL one would declare an index on age and income to speed up such a query, I am wondering what is the pandas way of doing this if any.

Comment: How are you currently doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "pandas way" of doing this query is:

```
df[(x < df.age) & (df.age < y) & (p < df.income) & (df.income < q)]
```

*pandas indexes everything by default (including all columns), so you don't need to explicitly declare beforehand what you are going to be querying.*

(I can't say whether this set up would makes sense for your dataset.)

Comment: "Pandas indexes everything by default" - that was what I was looking for!. I am currently already doing it like you have shown, and I see times of about ~30ms for a data set with 100K rows and was wondering if that is the fastest it can be done, or if I can use SQL and get it to go faster.

Comment: @jason have you tried timing the SQL? I expect pandas is much faster (for one thing it is in memory - although this means data is not persistent, which is one benefit of using a db)

Comment: I don't have an SQL setup handy at the moment to test, I plan to test it when I have it ready. But like you said, I would be very surprised if an in memory all-index data structure is slower than SQL. The data is readonly, so I don't need persistance anyway.

Comment: @AndyHayden : Do you happen to have a source for "Pandas indexes everything by default"? I couldn't find anything in the documentation referring to this. I would love to learn more.

Comment: @Xochipilli I'm not sure what I meant by that, each of these comparisons will be O(n). You can use .eval (numexpr) to do in a single pass.

Comment: @AndyHayden The original question asked how to put an SQL-like index on certain columns to speed up selecting by that column. In SQL relational databases these indexes typically use a B-tree giving you O(log(n)) lookup instead of a slow linear search over all rows.

You mentioned that _"pandas indexes everything by default (including all columns), so you don't need to explicitly declare beforehand what you are going to be querying."_ and I was wondering your source for that answer?

But since you're now talking about O(n) lookup I think we might be talking about different indices.

Comment: @xochipilli right, ithink I was misspeaking, will update this answer

Answer (score 3):

Pandas is really just a wrapper around `numpy.ndarray`.

All the searches are really done using `ndarray` internal.

```
 df[(df.age > x) & (y < df.age) & (df.income > p) & (df.income < q)]
```

should do the trick. But you could speed up the process by using `numpy.ndarray` directly or by using masked arrays: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html

These won't allocate new memory for your newly generated arrays. That means that you don't have the time/CPU overhead of looking and allocating new memory for your "filtered" results and that you won't have the memory overhead induced by the copy itself. (Actually, this is not completely true since the mask has to be stored somewhere, but you still don't have to copy your table *values* somewhere else in memory)

However, this comes at a cost: masked array are a bit longer to work with since the process has to check if each value in memory is masked. However, if this is just to "filter", this specific access overhead should be unnoticeable (it becomes quite important when one wants to do calculations with the masked array).

**EDIT:**

For persistent and optimized data access on disk and in memory, there is PyTables which is optimized that way. That said, Pytables as well as Numpy/Pandas were not thought to be used that way.

Comment: suppose I am querying a 100K row data and after applying the above 4 filters it turns out that it is only 100 row result set, then that copy is negligible (no?) - besides I need to return that data out to a consumer anyway, so I wouldn't gain anything by working around copy (no?)

Comment: You are right: in your case, copying won't induce much overhead. So you can ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

When manipulating a 40+ million row dataframe (dfBig), boolean indexing (in a loop) started to really be slow.

Here is some pseudo code that worked for me; basically split dfBig into a dictionary using df.groupby() and use the dictionary entries instead of explicit indexing:

```
# very slow version:
colValues = dfBig.SomeField1.unique()
indValues = dfBig.SomeField2.unique()
dfResult = ... # set up output dataframe
for col in colValues:
    for idx in indValues:
        boolIndex = (dfBig.SomeField1 == col) & (dfBig.SomeField2 == idx)
        fetchValue = dfBig[boolIndex]   # this takes a looong time
        dfResult.loc[idx, col] = someFuncion(fetchValue)


# much faster version:
dicCol = {x:y for x,y in df.groupby(SomeField1)}
for col,dfCol in dicCol.items():
    dfIdx = {x:y for x,y in dfCol.groupby(SomeField2)}
    for idx, dfIdx in dicIdx.items():
        dfResult.oc[idx, col] = someFunction(dfIdx)
```

"faster version" made it faster by about two orders of magnitude for the 40mm row dataframe

Comment: There would be a question of how many values you had in each column - what was the size of dictionaries.